# Python: MySQLdb LOAD DATA INFILE silently fails

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, load-data-infile

I am attempting to use a Python script to import a csv file into a MySQL database.
It seems to fail silently.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

class DB:
    host = 'localhost'
    user = 'root'
    password = '**************'
    sqldb = 'agriculture'
    conn = None

    def connect(self):
        self.conn =  MySQLdb.connect(self.host,self.user,self.password,self.sqldb )

    def query(self, sql, params=None):
        try:
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            if params is not None:
                cursor.execute(sql, params)
            else:
                cursor.execute(sql)
        except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError):
            self.connect()
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            if params is not None:
                cursor.execute(sql, params)
            else:
                cursor.execute(sql)

        print vars(cursor)
        return cursor

    def load_data_infile(self, f, table, options=""):
        sql="""LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE %s FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';""" % (f,table)
        self.query(sql)


db = DB()

pathToFile = "/home/ariggi/722140-93805-sqltest.csv"
table_name = "agriculture.degreedays"

db.load_data_infile(pathToFile, table_name)
```

In an attempt to debug this situation I am dumping the cursor object to the screen within the "query()" method. Here is the output:

> {'_result': None, 'description': None, 'rownumber': 0, 'messages': [],
>   '_executed': "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
>   '/home/ariggi/722140-93805-sqltest.csv' INTO TABLE degreedays FIELDS
>   TERMINATED BY ',';", 'errorhandler': >, 'rowcount': 500L, 'connection': , 'description_flags': None,
>   'arraysize': 1, '_info': 'Records: 500  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0 
>   Warnings: 0', 'lastrowid': 0L, '_last_executed': "LOAD DATA LOCAL
>   INFILE '/home/ariggi/722140-93805-sqltest.csv' INTO TABLE agriculture.degreedays
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';", '_warnings': 0, '_rows': ()}

If I take the "_last_executed" query, which is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/ariggi/722140-93805-sqltest.csv' INTO TABLE agriculture.degreedays FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

and run it through the mysql console it works as expected and fills the table with rows. However when I execute this script my database table remains empty.

I am pretty stumped and could use some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `db.conn.commit()` at the end of your code to make the changes permanent. Python by default does not use the "autocommit" mode, so until you issue a commit the DB module regards your changes as part of an incomplete transaction.

As @AirThomas points out in a comment it helps to us a "context manager" - though I'd say the correct formulation was

```
with conn.cursor() as curs:
    do_something_with(curs)
```

because this will automatically commit any changes unless the controlled code raises an exception.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I'm even more confused now because it was working earlier without the commit statement. If you run 2 queries without a commit, does the second query commit the first one?

Comment: @Mike If you use `with conn as cursor:` the module will give you a cursor to use inside the `with` block, and commit when you exit the block.

Comment: Great suggestion! I hope you don't mind me incorporating it in my answer (with due credit, naturally).

Comment: what's "db"? what's "conn"?